# Group by in one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have list of users and a visits table . I want a list of users whose profile has been viewed :

```
visits table
╔═════════════════╗
║ vistor  visited ║
╠═════════════════╣
║'26000', '26023' ║
║'26000', '26023' ║
║'26000', '26023' ║
║'26000', '26023' ║
║'26000', '26023' ║
║'26000', '26023' ║
║'26000', '26023  ║
║'26001', '26023' ║
║'26001', '26023' ║
║'26002', '26023' ║
║'26005', '26000  ║
║'26005', '26000' ║
║'26004', '26000' ║
╚═════════════════╝
```

I want number of views per user

```
╔═════════════════╗
║ visited  count  ║
╠═════════════════╣
║'26023',  3      ║
║'26000',  2      ║
╚═════════════════╝
```

Comment: Try GROUP BY and COUNT with DISTINCT in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want `count(distinct)`:

```
select visited, count(distinct visitor)
from t
group by visited;
```